# Button EventHandler c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm making a WebPage and I needed to display some search result in textbox that defined during run and make that *`textbox optional`* to appears if the user clicked on a `linkButton` its all worked right till I make the `textbox.visible = false` When I click on the link comes the error because `protected void LinkButton1_Click(..)` can't find the `text` and if I make textbox definition `public` only the last result from the reader will be shown

so is there any other way to control the click event ??

like:

```
if (link.click=true)
   text.visible=true;
```

I don't know if what I'm saying make any sense maybe the code below helps ..

Please help I'm desperate

I'm using visual studio, asp.net, c#

Pp is a panel

```
int i=1;
while (reader.Read())
{
    string moreinfo = reader["more_information"].ToString()
    TextBox text = new  TextBox();
    LinkButton ll = new LinkButton();
    ll.ID = "link" + i;
    ll.Text = "see more.. ";
    ll.Visible = true;
    pp.Controls.Add(ll);
    pp.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
    text.ID = "text" + i;
    text.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
    text.Text = moreinfo;
    pp.Controls.Add(text);
    text.Visible = false;
    ll.Click += new EventHandler(LinkButton1_Click);
    i++;
}
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    text.Visible = true;
    ll.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Because you are using ASP a web base, Code behind will only fire when there is a postback or the page is loaded. Would need to use JavaScript.  
How do you want to ---Display--- Unhide `i` amount of LinkButtons?

Comment: I want to display the textboxs that have been hidden (make it visible) when I click on the LinkButton  @juanvan

Comment: Where do you put the while loop? in Page_load? If so, make sure it is not called when postback. Also what is text and ll in LinkButton1_Click method? I don't see the definition.

Comment: yap in page_load .. ok, that's the problem, they supposed to be the 'TextBox' I want to make visible and the 'LinkButton' caused that they both defined locally, so that i don't want to use this method nor 'EventHandler(LinkButton1_Click)' @mattfei

Comment: Javascript is the only way to hide and unhide elements in HTML with out a page PostBack. Rework the question, using Javascript.

Comment: Ok .. thank you @juanvan